# Add margin when using

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap and a navbar with navbar-fixed-top class on it.
Below that is a div with an image inside (full width of the screen, height 400px).

The problem is that, since my navbar has a background-color, the navbar goes onto the image. I tried to add a margin-top:80px on the image, it works fine, but when I go below 769px x XXXpx, a space appears between my navbar and my image. I know this space is coming from the margin-top when resizing the window, but what could I do to set the image below the navbar without adding a margin-top for it to appear correctly ?

I thought this was simple issue so I didn't add code to my post, I will if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap CSS rule for image in

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    your CSS rule for image margin-top: 80px here
}
```